# Karma instead of God's plan

Tags: karma, western-philosophy, god, nihilism

Hello I wondered if the existence of karma (I believe in it anyway) can take the place of the concept of "God's plan" - which is how some people live with the horrors of Nihilism.

I am not a Christian but it seems to me that God's plan is what we humans are missing (existentially) since He died.

Comment: What are you expecting when you say "God's plan"?

Comment: It's difficult to understand this question. Are you simply asking, "Are Karma and God's Plan the same thing?"

Comment: no i'm asking about nihilism, and how people can live with themselves after the death of God

Comment: OK, that's a good question in itself, but how does that belong on Buddhism.SE?

Comment: i don't know, it seems to be about karma anyway

Comment: This is an interesting question. How can people live with themselves after the death of God. And it's not nihilistic but simply atheistic. **This question probably belongs on [Philosophy SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on philosophy.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Anthony not sure I agree, it has philosophical elements (e.g. death of god as nihilism) but it IS about Buddhist doctrine :)

Comment: OK I think I see where you are coming from. The question wording needs to be fixed; I will try to do it shortly.

Comment: What are you really asking, though? "Can karma be a source of comfort like God's Plan for Christians?" In that case the question is opinion-based and I would answer by saying "yes, but a practicing Buddhist should not rely on comfort."

Comment: I don't mean "comfort" as much as: can karma be a reason to suppose moral nihilism is not a fact?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

God's plan implies a working towards some goal, or a rhyme or reason at least. Karma implies no such thing; it simply describes an orderliness to the mental aspect of reality, in the same way that physics does for the physical aspect. Karma is in fact to be abandoned, or risen above, in the end, to the extent that one performs neither wholesome nor unwholesome karma as an enlightened being.

Simply put, Buddhism admits of no plan to samsara; it is utterly meaningless and to be risen above or abandoned in the end. Karma simply describes a part of the mechanics of the system and is not in fact all that important to Buddhist practice, in comparison to realization of the nature of reality as impermanent, suffering, and non-self.

Answer (score 0):

God's plan is someone else laying out your fate.Karma is you laying down your own fate.Karma is action done in the present moment.You can choose what you want to do in the present moment but have to live with the consequences.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily the case :) your first statement i mean :)

Comment: i don't have to invoke any xtian mysticism to show how your response is a little hot headed. even if God's plan is his and not ours, that doesn't mean we can't choose to "act... in the present but... live with the consequences". not to mention the history of xtians who argued for free will.

Comment: Orion you're welcome to add to your answer to make sure it makes sense to me tho :)

Comment: hey.. relax..man. lol..just breath in count to three then exhale.trust me Everything is going to be alright. This is an excellent question but i get confused when its unclear, your not a  Christian but your asking about Gods plan to a Buddhist...I think that you will find Christian SE to be more qualified In answering the Christian concept of free will or God's plan .by the way what is xtians?? sounds sci fi- ish. Are you just too lazy to type Christians aww thas cute :" >

Comment: No it's about nietzsche my breathing is fine thanks. I'm just trying to understand what you are talking about haha